pgfplots plot difference between columns of table gives wrong results
This code compiles fine, but gives wrong results:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
1,2,5
2,4,6
3,5,8
4,7,10
5,8,12
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}\mydata


\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={Absolute Error},
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},anchor=north},
    ]
    \addplot[green,mark=o] table[x index={0},y expr={\thisrowno{2}-\thisrowno{1}}] {\mydata};
    \addlegendentry{Absolute Error}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

Output:

What is wrong here? I want to build the difference between second and third column of the table.

Nothing fails - your code produces the correct output.

You probably have wrong data in data.csv.
If you are feeling brave, you could use
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{data.csv}

